# How does linker select dynamic library among those compiled with different compilers

Tags: c++, linker, dynamic-linking

I have a project in C++ which currently is not linked against any external dynamic library. I'm thinking about using some of boost libraries in future which need to be built (not header-only). For now, in the stage of development, I build my project with three different tool chains: `g++`, `LLVM/Clang++` and `Intel C++`, the platform is `Linux`. These compilers, AFAIK, are binary compatible with each other, e.g. g++-compiled app can use Intel C++-compiled dynamic library.

I've built boost binaries and installed them into different folders. e.g. `build_gcc`, `build_icc`. Then I added paths to these folders to the system `LIBRARY_PATH`. The question is: if I now build my project with either `g++` or `Intel C++` and link some dynamic library, e.g. write

```
-lboost_math_tr1
```

in the `makefile`, how does the linker decide which exact library file to link against if the binaries from different compilers are compatible with each other?

The motivation of the question is simple: `Intel C++` is an optimizing compiler, so if I build things with it, I expect them to be linked against dynamic library compiled with `Intel C++` compiler, not against the one compiled with `g++`. Of course, I know that I can simply use multiple conditional statements in the `makefile` to set the exact directories with library binaries for each used tool chain but it is just a bit inconvenient. I am wandering, is the linker smart enough to recognize which exact shared library file it should use or does it simply use the first occurrence found in the system `LIBRARY_PATH`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the linker won't know. if the first found library is incompatible, it will even bail out, rather than search all libs until it finds a compatible one.

confirm something like:

```
$ cat foo.c
int main() {
  return 0;
}
$ mkdir bar
$ touch bar/libm.so
$ gcc foo.c -o foo -Lbar -lm
/usr/bin/ld: error: b/libm.so: file is empty
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

otoh, the beauty of dynamic linking lies in being able to exchange the dylib with a better one, without having to recompile.
so you can link against the g++ version, but if performance is poor install the icc version on the target host (on a place that will be searched for before the g++-version) and your application will magically use it (as long as they are compatible).

you could also use the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` variable to search for libraries in a non-standard location when running your application:

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/path/to/super/libs/ ./app-dylinked-with-generic-libs
```

Comment: Simple yet complete explanation. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The PATH environment variable is used for finding executables, not for finding libraries.  Each compiler has a set of standard places it looks for libraries, plus places that are specified explicitly using -L.  It isn't going to care about which compiler created the library.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add these libraries to `$LIBRARY_PATH` (linking) and `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` (runtime) not the `$PATH`. I feel like you can set these variables in your `Makefile` one at a time to decide which binary to link against.